# What is the difference between cyclomatic coverage and branch coverage?

Tags: test-coverage

While studying for my exam for software development I noticed that I couldn't give an example of cyclomatic coverage (the coverage reached through base path testing) that would satisfy the requirements for branch coverage, nor vice versa. And when searching online, I could not find examples where both types are discussed on the same example graph.

Either they are different ways of defining the same thing or my understanding of one or both are wrong.

An example graph where cyclomatic coverage and branch coverage would be different would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no such thing as "cyclomatic coverage."  It's "branch coverage" and "cyclomatic complexity."  Branch coverage describes the quality of your tests.  Cyclomatic complexity describes the degree of branching.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My textbook describes cyclomatic coverage as the set of test cases which forms a base for the paths for the control graph (I probably didn't translate it 100% correct). The cyclomatic complexitity isn't the same thing as cyclomatic coverage, they are related: the cyclomatic complexity can be seen as the number of linear independent test cases you need in cyclomatic coverage.

Comment: Then your textbook has invented a new term for no particular reason.

Comment: If that's what your textbook says, then that's what you put on the test.  It wouldn't be the first time a textbook has made up a new term.

Comment: yet I have found other sources using the term... (a lot fewer than sources of other test coverage terms tho) Thanks anyway. Will leave this post open for a bit long (maybe 24h) (in case the term is real just rarely used)

Comment: Then feel free to post an answer to your own question (it's allowed and even encouraged!). Though I must agree with @RobertHarvey and CPerkins... I'm unfamiliar with the term, but a quick google reveals mostly nothing... with this very question as one of the top results, which is always a bad sign :)

Comment: You mentioned that you translated the definition, does that mean you translated the term as well or does the book use the English term?

Comment: The textbook uses a Dutch term but the first time it's mentioned it states that cyclomatic coverage is the correct English term.

Comment: Does the book say there is a difference between the two terms?